# What does linga literally mean in Shiva Linga?

Tags: shiva, shiva-lingam

I have read different stories about this on Quora. Some of my childhood friends would tell some different stories to me about this.

I need to know what it really means and why we worship it?

Comment: Avoid using such words in public site. I removed it!

Comment: @ParabrahmanJyoti oops. I didn't notice while writing. My intention was not that hope you understand.

Comment: It means Shiva's symbol. The word Linga means "symbol" literally. Genitals in human body are also called linga because it is a symbol to differentiate the gender. For more details : https://youtu.be/kWdyrWBLdKU

Answer (score 2):

This is answered in

- [Shiva Purana: Vidyeśvara-saṃhitā: Chapter 7 - Śiva manifests himself as a column of fire in the battlefield](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc225552.html)
- [Shiva Purana: Vidyeśvara-saṃhitā: Chapter 5 - The greatness of the phallic emblem (liṅga) of Śiva](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc225550.html)
- [Shiva Purana: Koṭirudra-Saṃhitā: Chapter 12 - The reason for Śiva’s assuming the phallic form (liṅga)](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226513.html)

**Meaning 1**

These chapters convey that in the beginning it was representation of **Shiva's Niṣkala (nameless and formless) aspect** or his representation as **piller/column of fire**.

**Meaning 2**

Later on,

> Lord Śiva said:—
>   45. O gods, O sages, you listen to my words with reverence. If my penis is supported in a vaginal passage there will be happiness.
>
> 46. Except Pārvatī, no other woman can hold my penis. Held by her my penis will immediately become quiet.
>
> ...
>
> 51. Śiva became delighted and so also Pārvatī, the mother of the universe. That phallus was held by her in that form then.

So, now, below is the meaning of it

> The pedestal shaped as the vagina and the phallus fixed therein are symbolical of the eternal creative forces personified as Śivā [Pārvatī] and Śiva.