# Is there any temple where Shiva is worshipped in the form of a pillar without pedestal?

Tags: shiva, temple, worship, shiva-lingam

As mentioned in [What does linga literally mean in Shiva Linga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36151/what-does-linga-literally-mean-in-shiva-linga/36155#36155) post,

> The pedestal shaped as the vagina and the phallus fixed therein are symbolical of the eternal creative forces personified as Śivā and Śiva.

The above mentioned form is found in most of the temples.

But before the story of Hāṭeśa, Shiva's Niṣkala (nameless and formless) aspect was just like a pillar which appeared in the Brahma-Vishnu conflict.

Is there any temple where Shiva is worshipped just as a pillar without any pedestal shaped as the vagina?

Comment: what do you think a stupa or a yupa-stambha is?

Comment: Buddhists just stole it, called own, then after Muslims too did same thing as Buddhists.

Comment: Pancha aaraamas (siva temples) in Andhra Pradesh have such stupas in temples @YDS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are [Pancha (5) aaraamas (Siva Temples)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancharama_Kshetras) in Andhra Pradesh.   The Sivalingas at these temples are made from a single Sivalinga.

[image]

Comment: Wow! Wasn't knowing this legend. I was only aware of panchabhuta shivalingas.