# Shape form of other God?

Tags: gods

Shape form of Shiva is like linga.. is there any such, non-human form of representation... like a shape form for other Gods.. like Vishnu, Saraswati, Lakshmi, Brahma..etc..

```
God - Non-Human form of representation
Shiva - Lingam
Vishnu - ?
Brahma - ?
```

[image: Shiva]

Comment: Does this answer your question https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15144/do-any-deities-other-than-the-pancha-mahadevatas-have-swayambhu-representation ?

Comment: @YDS It quite answers, I will wait someone to answer.. How did Shiva Lings concept came.. I mean who drew it first, how did people knew, it was related to GOD

Comment: You are confusing Shiva which is name of Brahman, with manifested Mahesha/Shankar. Br(A)hma, Vishn(U) and (M)ahesha are AUM(OM) or triguna prakriti or Shabda Brahman aka cause of the universe and represented by three lines on shivlinga. Shiva is nirguna formless and there is only one god represented by Shivlinga. Thats why Shankaracharya called himself 'Shivoham-I am Shiva' and he didnot mean Puranic god Shankara of Kailasha.

Comment: No this is not true. Depending on which school you are from God has a manifestation.

Comment: @HinduKid do you want something like [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/36155/12304)