# Where's this line from? "shanto bava maheshana"

Tags: shloka, reference-request

Where did this line come from?

> shanto bava maheshana

I think it's part of a shlok, but this is just some of it.

I tried searching online, but it didn't work though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are some minor mistakes in your transcription, but this is probably from the Shiva Purana, specifically chapter [8.12](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226513.html). (You can find a full translation of that particular chapter [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/54549/29157).)

This is [verse 41,](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-sanskrit/d/doc398744.html) to be exact:

> जगदादिर्जगद्योनिर्जगदन्तर्गतोपि च ।
> **शान्तो भव महेशान** सर्वांल्लोकांश्च पालय ॥ ४१ ॥
>
> jagadādirjagadyonirjagadantargatopi ca |
> **śānto bhava maheśāna** sarvāṃllokāṃśca pālaya || 41 ||

It translates to:

> You are the beginning of the universe, the origin of the universe within the universe. “O lord Śiva, be quiet. Protect all the worlds.”

The next line in the Shiva Purana explains that this mantra gives stability, happiness, etc.