# Shiv Puran Section 4 Chapter 12 ( Kotirudra Samhita Adhyay 12) states Shiv ling is Penis and Yoni is Vagina

Tags: shiva, puranas, shiva-purana, shiva-lingam

In the mentioned Chapter, Rishi Suta explains the story behind Shivling. In the translations it states that Shivji appeared in front of wives of Sages holding his penis in his hand and sages curse him that his penis falls on the ground and later it is established in Vagina of Parvati as per the translation to stabilize it. Whereas in other texts, in most of them, it states that Shivlinga is the Formless Universe and the Yoni, its Origin or Source. So it must mean the previous one is wrong. Are the translations wrong or the Puranas are modified to look like Shivlinga is Shivji's penis to make it look bad. Then we also have the Gudimallam Shivlinga, one of the oldest, which looks like a penis which further backs up this fact. Do you have any answers on what is correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct translation for Shiva purana -4:12?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/43795/correct-translation-for-shiva-purana-412)

Comment: I have read this one but it seems their are 2 perspectives mixed. Also that story seems wrong since this happened after the Sati incident and Parvati mata herself worshipped Shivlinga to get Lord Shiva as her husband so how can she be present their to provide for Yoni. This seems modified by Anti-Hindus to cause dispute.

Comment: Linga(sanskr.) is core essence .Sri Rudram has shlokas of core essences(linga).Western misunderstanding the translatory word, or significance, concept, spirituality, Sanskrit , purposely?creating a negative, which spreads like wildfire. The scriptures say the mind of a lavish meat eater will be filled with amorous urges. How then can they pause and "see" eternal truths. Even so many westerners have understood. And they do not spread this fallacy. And even now we who mistakenly get confused should understand the depth of scripture which is over 8000 years old.(dating by bronze age collapse)

Comment: Shiva puran chapter - 1 answers your query.

Comment: @Abhas, from your clue, I read it. It details how the embodied and disembodied forms of linga appeared and how they were then assigned

Comment: @ajitdas It is important to note that Shiva Linga is NOT a body organ, but a structure that differentiates the masculine and feminine aspects of the Brahman.

Comment: Yes. Nothing to do with the shapes and material of this world. The clarification completes your point.